# Delay on receiving block by peered node

Tags: private-blockchain, synchronization, proof-of-authority, protocol, clique

Sometimes it takes an around of `25ms` to import new block by the other peered node after mined by miner. But sometimes it increases directly around `400ms` to import block by peered node after mined by miner.  In PoA: Clique consensus there is no such delay I found.

```
Is this due to latency ?  
ans : No, Ideally zero latency for same machine/region
```

And my question is,

> 1. What is the reason for the non-uniform block receiving delay?

Comment: CLique consensus relies on authority in making blocks, which can't be given easily. So basically you have to wait because an other distant node has the authority to make a new block and your node doesn't. 
based on the above you can say that network delays, data reading, writing and processing delays can cause the mentioned effect.